# swift - how to parse logo image from m3u playlist

Tags: swift, parsing, m3u, iptv

I have a parsing m3u playlist url but I can't parse image url too?

all source code from GitHub : https://github.com/ArtemStepuk/zombobox

```
extension IPTVM3U8PareserService: M3U8ParserService {
func extractChannelsFromRawString(_ string: String) -> [Channel] {
    var channels = [Channel]()
    string.enumerateLines { line, shouldStop in
        if line.hasPrefix("#EXTINF:") {
            let infoLine = line.replacingOccurrences(of: "#EXTINF:", with: "")
            let infoItems = infoLine.components(separatedBy: ",")
            if let title = infoItems.last {
                let channel = Channel(title: title, url: nil, logo: nil)
                channels.append(channel)
            }
        } else {
            if var channel = channels.popLast() {
                channel.url = URL(string: line)
                channels.append(channel)
            }
        }
    }
    return channels
}
```

Any suggestions to parsing the channel logo is provided by `tvg-logo`.

example:

```
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-logo="http://i.cdn.turner.com/adultswim/big/video/mainstream/liveStream.jpg" group-title="USA",[AS] Live Stream
http://adultswimhls-i.akamaihd.net/hls/live/238460/adultswim/main/1/master_Layer5.m3u8
```

Comment: how to solved this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//You can do this, and linkIm3 gives you the url for the image    
let val2 = line.components(separatedBy: " ")
for sep in val2{
    if sep.hasPrefix("tvg-logo="){
        let sep2 = sep.components(separatedBy: ",")
        let sep1 = sep2[0]
        let indexStartOfText = sep1.index(sep1.startIndex, offsetBy: 10)
        linkIm2 = String(sep1[indexStartOfText...])
        let indexEndOfText = linkIm2.index(linkIm2.endIndex, offsetBy: -1)
        linkIm3 = String(linkIm2[..<indexEndOfText])
     }
 }
```